# Tomcat with Shared Libs in a bundled Jar

Tags: java, apache-camel, shared-libraries, cxf, tomcat8

is it possible to create a bundled Jar and add it to the shared-libs folder at my tomcat installation?

I have multiple projects that are using the camel packages, so i tried to put the jars to tomcat/libs and it works fine. But it would be nicer if i could add all the single jars to a bundled one.

I tried already with the one-jar-plugin: https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/
But there, the output of tomcats says that it couldn't find the cxfservlet class.

With the Maven-Assembly-Plugin i get the error message that it couldn't find the namespacecontext of camel-cxf.

Do you have any other ideas what i can do? Or is it impossible?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: If you need jar with just Camel packages in it, then maybe the easiest would be to unzip Camel jars to one directory, then zip it back into one jar. The one-jar-plugin creates one jar, but with whole project, with all dependencies, and it seems that that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To create a big (uber) JAR then also the manifest and meta data files must be included correctly.

See this FAQ and the JIRA link how to do this properly:

- http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-a-big-uber-jar.html

Comment: Hey, thanks, this helped me a lot. But i still have an issue while starting camel with my cxf-Endpoint. It seems that the WSDL could not be found from the uber-jar with camel files, while my wsdl remains in the war file.

I get this error-message:
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.NullPointerException
........
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.WSDLServiceFactoryBean.getDefinition(WSDLServiceFactoryBean.java:64)

Any ideas what i can do to fix it?